# Group fields of multiple measurements into one record (InfluxDB - Flux - C#)

Tags: c#, influxdb, flux

I am writing IoT Data to an InfluxDB. One measurement contains, besides the Time and DeviceId, multiple values (Temp and Humidity).

I can visualize the data in Grafana without any problem.

Now I am writing an API on this data in C#. I can get the data out of my InfluxDB using the InfluxDB.Client.Core and InfluxDB.Client namespaces from NuGet. But every value of one measurement (= Temp and Humidity measured on a specific time on a specific device) seems to be returned as a single line.
This means that if, for example, I get data in a specified timeframe where a device sends 5 measurements, I get 10 lines in which the value field of my query equals only a single value (Temp and Humid).

I would like to combine the 2 values into a single json object. Is there a way to do this in the flux query or do I have to combine this myself in the C# code?

Desired output:

```
[{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:00", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"20", "Humidity": "56"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:03", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"20", "Humidity": "55"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:06", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"21", "Humidity": "52"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:09", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"21", "Humidity": "50"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:12", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"21", "Humidity": "50"}]
```

I used the following code to print the lines as a test, the values are printed to the console output one at a

```
var influxDBClient = InfluxDBClientFactory.Create("localhost:8086", "admin", "pw");


var flux = "from(bucket:\"tmsmm\") |> range(start: " + From + " ,stop: " + To + ") |> " +
               "filter(fn: (r) => r.device_id == \"" + DeviceId + "\"  and " +
               "r._measurement == \"indoormeter\" and " +
               "(r._field == \"Temp\" or r._field == \"Humid\"))";
            


var fluxTables = await influxDBClient.GetQueryApi().QueryAsync(flux, "smm");

fluxTables.ForEach(fluxTable =>
{
    var fluxRecords = fluxTable.Records;
    fluxRecords.ForEach(fluxRecord =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{fluxRecord.GetTime()}: {fluxRecord.GetValue()}");
    });
});
```

Output:

```
20
20
21
21
21
56
55
52
50
50
```

I tried the following code to save the data in an object of the class Measurement:

```
var flux = "from(bucket:\"tmsmm\") |> range(start: " + From + " ,stop: " + To + ") |> " +
               "filter(fn: (r) => r.device_id == \"" + DeviceId + "\"  and " +
               "r._measurement == \"indoormeter\" and " +
               "(r._field == \"Temp\" or r._field == \"Humid\"))";
var fluxTables = await influxDBClient.GetQueryApi().QueryAsync<Measurement>(flux, "tmsmm");
```

With the following class Measurement:

```
public class Measurement
    {

        [@Column("DeviceId")]
        public string DeviceId {get;set;}

        [@Column(IsTimestamp = true)]
        public DateTime time {get;set;}

        [@Column("Temp")]
        public float Temp {get;set;}

        [@Column("Humid")]
        public double Humid {get;set;}

    }
```

The rest of my program returns this IEnumerable to requests on the API as a json. The DateTime and DeviceId are fine, but the Temp and Humid values are empty. Plus I get 10 measurements. This is the output that I get:

```
[{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:00", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:03", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:06", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:09", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:12", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:00", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:03", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:06", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:09", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"},
{"DateTime":"2021-11-18 10:00:12", "DeviceId":"1", "Temp":"0", "Humidity": "0"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that with Flux, you should look into the [pivot](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/pivot/) function:

```
data
  |> pivot(
    rowKey:["_time"],
    columnKey: ["_field"],
    valueColumn: "_value"
  )
```

This example comes from the flux doc:
[Align fields within each measurement that have the same timestamp](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/pivot/#align-fields-within-each-measurement-that-have-the-same-timestamp)